# Judgemental equalities of path composition

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I have yet another question about Cubical Type Theory, this time involving path composition.

I think I have grasped the face systems and formation of the `comp` primitive. However, the way it reduces in particular cases is a big mystery to me.

In the following section, let `A,X` be types, `p,q` paths (their orientation should be clear from context), `a,b,x,...` points. Endpoints of the interval are `1i` and `0i`.

For example, does `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => <_> b]` produce `p`?

What is the difference between `<i> comp X (p @ i) []` and `<i> comp X (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a]`? Is an omitted face bound the same as identity-path face bound?

How does one prove that `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => q]` and `comp (<i> Path A a (q @ i)) p []` are the same? Or are they?

Last but not least, does it matter which paths we use in the face bounds? I mean what is the difference between `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => q]` and `<i> comp (<_> A) b [(i=0i) => <j> p @ -j, (i=1i) => q]`?

The corresponding cubes are:

```
a - - - - > c
^           ^
|           |
| <_> a     | q
|           |
|     p     |
a --------> b          (comp1)
```

```
a - - - - > c
^           ^
|           |
| inv p     | q
|           |
|   <_> b   |
b --------> b          (comp2)
```

I think they ought to be equal, but how does one derive such a judgement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the most expert in this stuff (I learned some stuff writing this up); more someone who fools around with an implementation (cubical Agda) and reading papers. As an aside, do you have an actual implementation to fool around with? Some of these questions can be answered by actually trying them out.

> For example, does `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => <_> b]` produce `p`?

No (`hcomp` is a homogeneous version of `comp` that is primitive in Agda, which is appropriate because your `<_> A` is constant):

```
hmm : (x y : A) (p : x ≡ y) → x ≡ y
hmm x y p i = hcomp (λ{ _ (i = i0) → x ; _ (i = i1) → y }) (p i)

hmmm : (x y : A) (p : x ≡ y) → p ≡ hmm x y p
hmmm x y p = refl -- this doesn't work
```

I *think* the important thing to keep in mind is that the 'system' (or whatever the face specification is called in what you're reading) specifies exactly the cases where `comp` reduces away (*completely*) due to dimensional refinements. So, in this case, when `i = i0` it reduces to `x` and when `i = i1` it reduces to `y`, and in between it does not reduce. And so:

> What is the difference between `<i> comp X (p @ i) []` and `<i> comp X (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a]`? Is an omitted face bound the same as identity-path face bound?

If you omit all faces, the `comp` doesn't reduce away *regardless* of the choice of `i`. Incidentally, the type of `hcomp` in Agda is:

```
hcomp  : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} {φ : I} (u : ∀ i → Partial φ A) (a : A) → A
```

`Partial φ A` is the type of the face system. `φ` tells you where `hcomp` reduces away. It does so when `φ = i1`. So you can write:

```
always : (x : A) → A
always x = hcomp {φ = i1} (λ _ _ → x) x
```

And this reduces to `x`. In order to give the empty system using a pattern, we need to write:

```
never : (x : A) → A
never x = hcomp {φ = i0} (λ _ ()) x
```

And this doesn't reduce further (`λ _ ()` could be written `λ _ → empty` and the `{φ = i0}` could be omitted) unless we know something about `x`/`A`. Usually the specification of the system is enough to infer `φ`, I guess, so cubical Agda makes it an implicit argument.

> How does one prove that `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => q]` and `comp (<i> Path A a (q @ i)) p [] are the same? Or are they?`

```
module _ (x y z : A) (p : x ≡ y) (q : y ≡ z) where
  r : x ≡ z
  r i = hcomp (λ{ _ (i = i0) → x ; k (i = i1) → q k}) (p i)

  s : x ≡ z
  s = comp (λ i → Path A x (q i)) {φ = i0} (λ _ ()) p
```

`comp` with an empty face is actually one way of specifying another primitive operation in cubical Agda:

```
transp : ∀ {ℓ} (A : (i : I) → Set (ℓ i)) (φ : I) (a : A i0) → A i1
```

Homogeneous composition (`hcomp`) and moving around in a heterogeneous type (`transp`) are divided into separate 'simpler' operations, and `comp` is derived. So, in Agda, `s` reduces to:

```
-- the computer told me this
hcomp (λ i → empty) (transp (λ i → x ≡ q i) i0 p)
```

As an intermediate step, it will help me to define just the `transp` part, which has the same type:

```
  s' : x ≡ z
  s' = transp (λ i → x ≡ q i) i0 p
```

This can be proved equal to `s` by taking advantage of how `φ`/faces cause `hcomp` to reduce, and how *systems* themselves reduce. The proof is probably a good enough example:

```
  simpler : s ≡ s'
  simpler i = hcomp (λ{ _ (i = i1) → s'}) s'
```

So, when `i = i1`, this reduces to `s'`, so the right side is valid. Because we haven't specified an `i = i0` face, the `hcomp` doesn't reduce away at that end. But, the system gets refined to throw away contradictory cases, like `(i0 = i1)`. So at the left end, the system reduces to the empty system, and we're left with the reduced term I gave for `s`.

Now, the final proof is going to involve knowing the last (I think) way that `comp` can reduce. If `A` is not simply an abstract type, then `comp` can reduce due to type-specific rules. The simplest example I can think of is this:

```
nat : ℕ
nat = hcomp {φ = i0} (λ{ _ () }) 1

canonical : nat ≡ 1
canonical = refl
```

So, even though `hcomp` with the empty system doesn't reduce in general, for concrete values it does reduce (this also means that for your first question, *particular* choices of `p` might cause the answer to be 'yes' instead). There are reduction rules for every type former commuting through `(h)comp` and `transp`, and this means that the following equation holds (the `λ where` syntax lets me write things with indentation instead of braces and semicolons):

```
  -- the computer almost told me this (it used a worse syntax)
  reduct : ∀ i → s' i ≡ hcomp (λ where
                                 k (i = i0) → transp (λ _ → A) k x
                                 k (i = i1) → transp (λ _ → A) k (q k))
                              (transp (λ _ → A) i0 (p i))
  reduct i = refl
```

Now, `transp` has similar reduction cases to `comp`, even though there's no system involved. Its second visible argument is `φ`, and it reduces away completely when `φ = i1`. The rule for choosing `φ` is that its first argument must be judgmentally constant when `φ = i1`. In the above case it's always constant, so we could pick whatever we want.

So, hopefully it's not too hard to see that `s' i` has actually reduced to `r i` with some extra `transp` noise thrown in. The way you get rid of that is similar to the above `hcomp` trick: you use `transp` with a `φ` such that it reduces at one end, and doesn't at the other. So for instance:

```
  reducti0 : x ≡ transp (λ _ → A) i0 x
  reducti0 i = transp (λ _ → A) (~ i) x

  reductik : ∀ k → transp (λ _ → A) k (q k) ≡ q k
  reductik k i = transp (λ _ → A) (k ∨ i) (q k)
```

So we can prove that `r` and `s'` are equivalent like so:

```
  complicated : r ≡ s'
  complicated j i
    = hcomp (λ where
        k (i = i0) → transp (λ _ → A) (k ∨ ~ j) x
        k (i = i1) → transp (λ _ → A) (k ∨ ~ j) (q k))
        (transp (λ _ → A) (~ j) (p i))
```

When `j = i0`, `~ j = k ∨ ~ j = i1` and all these `transp`s disappear. When `j = i1`, `~ j = i0` and `k ∨ ~ j = k`, and the `transp` terms match `s'`.

> Last but not least, does it matter which paths we use in the face bounds? I mean what is the difference between `<i> comp (<_> A) (p @ i) [(i=0i) => <_> a, (i=1i) => q]` and `<i> comp (<_> A) b [(i=0i) => <j> p @ -j, (i=1i) => q]`?

If you only care about the endpoints, it doesn't matter much. However, in the middle, they will not be judgmentally equal. So the choice will affect which higher equivalences are easier to prove and whatnot.

If you create the filled squares instead, then they will reduce to different things on different edges, so those will also be judgmentally different.

They can be proved equivalent by pulling things around corners and such, though.

```
  t : x ≡ z
  t i = hcomp (λ{ k (i = i0) → p (~ k) ; k (i = i1) → q k }) y

  mediate : r ≡ t
  mediate j i
    = hcomp (λ where
          k (i = i0) → p (~ k ∧ j)
          k (i = i1) → q k)
        (p (j ∨ i))
```

The *exact* details of all this are dependent on the primitives chosen. Agda has `hcomp` and `transp` as its primitive operations. Some papers I've seen use `comp` and derive those two as special cases. There's also Cartesian cubical type theory which has a somewhat different `comp` operation (and doesn't have `∧` and `∨`). But all of them will have some way to get the results above, I think.

Again, though, I'd recommend getting an implementation of this and using it on a computer. It is the computer's job to manipulate the judgmental equalities for you, so you can ask it these questions and get much faster answers. And probably you can look at a much larger body of proofs to figure out the tricks necessary to do the proofs like your last two sorts of questions.

Comment: So the composition operation introduces _a lot_ of additional paths besides reflexivity by recurrently putting reflexivities and `comp`s with reflexivities inside the face systems, right? That's actually neat, it concretises the intuition of the J axiom (paths generated by `refl`s).

About the implementation, I'm actually developing one myself :D I wanted to create a dependent type checker with actual Path types, not just Ids. I've waded through the CCHM paper and seen the cases on concrete types, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: I see. Implementing it is a good way to understand certain aspects of it certainly. You're forced to study each individual rule really well. I think the hard part is getting from that to how they combine to accomplish things, and that's where a completed implementation helps. I didn't really know what `s' i` was going to do until I asked the computer, for instance. Especially the `comp` rule for `Path` has a lot of auxiliary definitions to even describe its reduction behavior.

Comment: Oh, incidentally, I'm kind of negative on the 'paths are generated by refl' outlook. It was very clever of Martin-löf to come up with it, but I actually think some of the defects of MLTT arise from only induction working well (and so, functions do not, for instance). Cubical arguably moves away from justifying this view, and doing so is what allows it to incorporate things like higher inductive types, or proper coinductive types. `J` still exists, of course, but I think it's good to move away from the idea that this is due to path types being inductively defined.